# How do I create a flag so each user gets to set one flag on one instance of a content type?

Tags: 7, rules, flags

I want to create a non-global flag which each user can use to 'flag' one (and only one) instance of a specific content type.

I have a view which displays a list of content with fields, including a flag link.  I would like to set up my flag (or a rule with a flag) so that if a user clicks on a flag link, all other flags that that user has set (for that specific flag type) are reset.

This will be used for a 'favorite' type of flag, which can only be set on one instance of a specific content type.

Comment: Do you mean user can flag only one node of a content type.. When he flags other node of same content type previous flag will be reset so that at any point of time user can mark only one node of particular content type ? Have you tried rules module ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.  I am using rules, but I am not sure how to write a rule that does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I eventually solved this

Create a rule that does the following actions.

1. Loop through a list of all content that the flagging user has flagged (with the specified flag.)
2. Unflag ALL of the nodes in this list
3. Re-flag the node that triggered the event (F\flagged-node)